# How do I instal Connector/J on windows 7?

Tags: java, mysql, windows, jdbc, connector-j

I need step by step instructions.
I have downloaded if from the mysql website http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/

But now I am not to sure what to do from here?
I'm sort of stuck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the JAR file in the runtime classpath. This is not environment-dependent.

How exactly to do that depends on what kind of application it is. If it's for example a plain vanilla Java application which you execute by `java.exe`, then use the `-cp` argument to specify the classpath.

```
java -cp .;/path/to/mysql.jar com.example.Foo
```

The classpath is basically a collection of paths to JAR files and/or `.class` files where Java should look for class definitions.

#### See also:

- [Java connectivity with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358) - A mini tutorial

Answer (score 0):

In a more direct form... Add the jar file to

C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\java\modules\ext

That being your version of netbeans and boom, good to go